# Resize Windows partition from USB boot disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

When I try to install Ubuntu from a USB Boot pen drive, there is an option to manually manage the partitions. Right now my HDD has one Windows 10 partition that used 100% of the device's storage (even though it only uses 5% of its capacity).

If I resize the Windows partition from the USB Boot live install, could I damage the Windows 10 partition?

Comment: You can use GPARTED from the live usb to shrink the windows partition. It will take a time! It will not damage the Windows 10 partition

Comment: So with GParted it will work? But not with the installer?

Comment: @Carl The Ubuntu installer uses the same engine for partition changes most likely. It should be as safe as with GParted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend to **shrink the Windows partition with Windows tools** (from within Windows). But do **not** use Windows to create new partitions. Instead *leave unallocated drive space*. (Windows would probably create dynamic partitions, and such partitions cannot be used by Ubuntu.)

If you shut down Windows, it might use *'fast startup'* which is a kind of hibernation. If you want access from Ubuntu to the Windows partition (or better) a common NTFS data partition, you should turn off fast startup in Windows.

Then reboot from a live USB or DVD drive and **use `gparted` to create the partitions you want for Ubuntu** (use the unallocated drive space).

Comment: +1 To this answer - there shouldn't really be any problem using GParted or the installation Live USB to shrink your Windows partition, but I'd prefer to ask Windows to 'shrink itself' & let you know it's happy before installing Ubuntu, *just in case*. As a new user, I'd go one step further and shrink as much space off the Windows partition as I wanted for Ubuntu *and then just leave it as blank*. During installation you can choose to 'Install Ubuntu alongside Windows' and the installer will use up the space you've made for it without you having to think about it.