# making space on a windows partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a new laptop with a 30gb ssd disk. my windows 10 takes up 12gb so I should be able to create a 10gb partition to install ubuntu.  I can't when I use windows tool to resize my hard drive it only offers 500Mb.  is there a windows hidden file which can't be moved for some reason.  is there a 3rd party tool that will safely resize a windows 10 partition

Comment: You can use `gparted` from Ubuntu LiveUSB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize Windows partition from USB boot disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071662/resize-windows-partition-from-usb-boot-disk)

Comment: 12 GB for Windows and 10 GB for Ubuntu doesn't sound adequate.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: In my experience, a smallish Ubuntu will happily live in 8 GB; Windows is...more demanding.

Comment: I agree. 10Gb for BASE and an empty /home is enough. But that does state you store personal documents elsewhere (so not in ~/$USER/Documents or Downloads but on a different partition). apache and mysql require more if used :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [GParted](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) (GParted is also available in the standard Ubuntu live ISO: just run `sudo gparted` )

Note that resizing a system partition always has some risks: I used this (and similar) many times successfully, accidentally erased a drive once, **so take a full system backup before proceeding**

The process is "make sure there's enough free space on the Windows partition, then resize it to the smaller size" - GParted will move data around, but will refuse to operate on a full partition. After you're done with that, you should have some space in which you can put your Linux partition(s).

Comment: There is no need to create a special Gparted LiveUSB, because Ubuntu installer contains it already.

Comment: Excellent, good to know, added to answer. (Haven't installed from a linuxless system for some time now)

Comment: the problem with gparted is that it doesn't move windows data to a safe place on the windows partition before making the partition

Comment: @rhubarbdog: Oh? Always did, in my experience - in case you *resize* the Windows partition down (needs to have enough free space); DO NOT remove and recreate, that's a DESTRUCTIVE process which doesn't make backups.